Formula to calculate Total number of test accounts required to perform load test using JMeter
I'm setting up a load test in JMeter and want to calculate how many test accounts I need. I have the following test parameters:

Test duration: 600 seconds
Time per iteration (for each user): 2 seconds
Concurrent users: 100

I am using this formula to calculate the total number of accounts required:
Total accounts required = (Test duration /Time per iteration) * concurrent users
Is this formula correct for calculating the number of unique accounts required for my test, assuming each user should use a different account for each iteration? If not, what adjustments should I make?

The formula is very simple: 1 thread (virtual user) - 1 account
Given you properly configure JMeter to behave like a real browser each virtual user must exactly represent real user with all its stuff like cookies, headers, cache, think times, etc.
If after iteration is done you want the user to look like "new" and not "returning" - untick the relevant box in the Thread Group:

